# Is it possible to attach ssh session(non tmux) on another tmux session?

Tags: tmux

The reason I ask this question is as follows. for example,

I usually work on a Windows PC by connecting to the build server with an ssh shell.
Then, in the state of executing a task that takes a long time
If I want to leave work even though the task has not been stopped, I have to turn on the PC and leave the office.
In this case, if I executed the task on tmux in advance, even if I turn off my PC and leave the office, there is no problem.

In this case, I wonder if there is any way to make it as if it was executed in tmux even if it is not executed in tmux in advance.

Is there any way?